# palindrome of a string in java

Tags: java

The constraint of the question is that:
The first line contains two integers N and L
N, denoting the number of person and L,the maximum length of a person's name in Palindrome respectively.
The ith of the next N lines contains a single string S denoting the name of the ith person.
 They can do that by choosing at most two non-overlapping substrings of their own name and reversing them.

My code is compiled properly but is giving run time error: So what needs to be changed?
 here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Palindrome {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        {
            String line = br.readLine();
            int N = Integer.parseInt(line);
            int l = Integer.parseInt(line);
            String a[] = new String[N];
            int c = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter names");
                a[i] = br.readLine();
            }
            String reverse[] = new String[N];

            int arrayLength = a.length;

            for (int i = arrayLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                reverse[i] = reverse[i] + a[i].charAt(i);
            }
            if (Arrays.equals(a, reverse)) //if (a[i].equals(reverse[i]))
            {
                c++;

                System.out.println(c);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to print the number of persons that can change their name to Palindrome form.

Example:

```
Input:        
   4 10            
   aacbaac
   acbdabc
   abcdcba
   abcbd
```

and

```
output:
   3
```

here 4 denotes total number of person
10 denotes the maximum length of each person name

output is 3 as only first 3 person can change their name to its respective form..

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: What's 3 in your input?

Answer (score 0):

One issue you have is that you defined a string array, but you're trying to pass characters into it. You should make `String reverse[] =new String[N];`
 into `Char reverse[] =new Char[N];`

Also, this `reverse[i] = reverse[i] + a[i].charAt(i);` should just be `reverse[i] = a[i].charAt(i);`

Comment: `reverse[i] = a[i].charAt(i);` must be `reverse[i] = String.valueOf(a[i].charAt(i));` else error.

Answer (score 0):

I presume this is a Codechef problem. The primary problem in your code is in the part where you assign the values to `N` and `l`. Notice that you take the input in `line` just once and then assign it's integer value to both `N` and `l`. So, the problem is that **your program is not taking an expected input**: you have to take the input in `line` **twice**. Change that part to

```
String line = br.readLine();
int N = Integer.parseInt(line);
line = br.readLine(); //add this line before assigning l's value
int l= Integer.parseInt(line);
```

Besides, what you are trying to do in the loop while finding the reverse of the string should be done in a nested loop construct. To abandon that complication, forget the second `reverse` array; you can use this one line statement to check for a palindrome string:

```
for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    if(String.valueOf(new StringBuffer(a[i]).reverse()).equalsIgnoreCase(a[i]))
        //a[i] is a palindrome, do whatever you want to
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it to a `StringBuilder` inorder to reverse it. Review the code below:

```
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String line = br.readLine();
        int N = Integer.parseInt(line);
        int l = Integer.parseInt(line);
        String a[] = new String[N];
        int c = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter names");
            a[i] = br.readLine();
        }
        String reverse[] = new String[N];

        int arrayLength = a.length;

        for (int i = arrayLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder(a[i]);

            reverse[i] = build.reverse().toString();
            if (a[i].equals(reverse[i])) {
                c++;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Pal is " + c);

    }
```

I don't know what you are using the `int` variable `l` for, but modify it like I have done above with the `N`.